# Genealogytree, make divorce appear

Tags: genealogytree

Good evening, I just found out this package to create genealogy tree, and I'm playing around, but encountered a problem. How do I make th divorce notation appear in my tree??

I've seen in the package documentation the option "divorce" with the symbole exist, yet cant make it appear.

I've tried a lot of variation:

- divorce (as opposed to marriage)
- divorced
- Divorce
- Divorced

But nothing. In my MWE I started using the template used for the Friedrich Gauss example.
Don't pay attention at the leggend overlapping the mother cell, I'll figure it in a second time.

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{hyperref} % per i riferimenti ipertestuali

\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\usepackage{incgraph}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}

    \begin{genealogypicture}[
        processing=database,
        database format=medium marriage below,
        node size=2.4cm,
        level size=3.5cm,
        level distance=6mm,
        list separators hang,
        name font=\bfseries,
        surn code={\textcolor{red!50!black}{#1}},
        place text={\newline}{},
        date format=d.mon.yyyy,
        tcbset={male/.style={colframe=blue,colback=blue!5},
                female/.style={colframe=red,colback=red!5}
                },
        box={fit basedim=7pt,boxsep=2pt,segmentation style=solid,
            halign=flush left,before upper=\parskip1pt,
            \gtrDBsex,drop fuzzy shadow,
            if image defined={add to width=25mm,right=25mm,
                underlay={
                        \begin{tcbclipinterior}\path[fill overzoom DBimage]
                            ([xshift=-24mm]interior.south east) rectangle (interior.north east);
                        \end{tcbclipinterior}
                    },
                }{},
            },
        edges=rounded,
        symbols record reset,
        after tree={\node[font=\scriptsize\itshape,text width=1.8cm,below left,
            fill=white,fill opacity=0.4,text opacity=1]
            at (current bounding box.north east) {\gtrSymbolsLegend};
            },
        ]
        %input{my.Surname.graph}
        
        sandclock{
            child[id=padre]{
                g[id=TGJ30]{
                    male,
                    name={\pref{T} G \surn{mySurname}},
                    birth={1957-08-28}{pCity},
                    marriage={1986-08-08}{Tavenre},
        %            death={}{},
                }
                p[id=JJB59]{
                    female,
                    name={\pref{J} J \surn{maidSurname}},
                    birth={1959-05-15}{mCity},
                    marriage={1986-08-08}{wed-City},
                    divorce={2012-05-08}{cityDIV},
        %            death={}{},
                    comment={\textbf{maidSurname \ref{sec:maidSurname}}},
                }
                c[id=FTJ90]{
                    male,
                    name={\pref{F} T  \surn{mySurname}},
                    birth={1990-05-23}{City}
                }
                c[id=BMJ93]{
                    male,
                    name={\pref{B} M \surn{mySurname}},
                    birth={1993-11-05}{City}
                }
                c[id=CGJ93]{
                    male,
                    name={\pref{C} G \surn{mySurname}},
                    birth={1993-11-05}{City},
                }
            %parent[id=D32]
            }
        }
        
    \end{genealogypicture}

\end{document}
```

PS. If there is a way to put the marriage symbol over the link between mother and father, it will be kindly apreciate.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `database format=full marriage below,` to bring up the divorce symbol.

[image: c]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{genealogypicture}[
        processing=database,
        database format= full marriage below,%changed <<<<<<<<
        node size=2.4cm,
        level size=3.5cm,
        level distance=6mm,
        list separators hang,
        name font=\bfseries,
        surn code={\textcolor{red!50!black}{#1}},
        place text={\newline}{},
        date format=d.mon.yyyy,
        tcbset={male/.style={colframe=blue,colback=blue!5},
            female/.style={colframe=red,colback=red!5}
        },
        list separators={\par}{ }{}{},
        box={fit basedim=7pt,boxsep=2pt,segmentation style=solid,
            halign=flush left,before upper=\parskip1pt,
            \gtrDBsex,drop fuzzy shadow,
            if image defined={add to width=25mm,right=25mm,
                underlay={
                    \begin{tcbclipinterior}\path[fill overzoom DBimage]
                        ([xshift=-24mm]interior.south east) rectangle (interior.north east);
                    \end{tcbclipinterior}
                },
            }{},
        },
        edges=rounded,
        symbols record reset,
        after tree={\node[font=\scriptsize\itshape, below right,
        fill=white,fill opacity=0.4,text opacity=1, anchor=center]
        at ([xshift=0.5mm, yshift=-1.2mm]TGJ30.south east) {\gtrsymMarried}; %changed <<<<<
        },
        ]   
        sandclock{
            child[id=padre]{
                g[id=TGJ30]{
                    male,
                    name={\pref{T} G \surn{mySurname}},
                    birth={1957-08-28}{pCity},
                    marriage={1986-08-08}{Tavenre},
                    %            death={}{},
                }
                p[id=JJB59]{
                    female,
                    name={\pref{J} J \surn{maidSurname}},
                    birth={1959-05-15}{mCity},
                    marriage={1986-08-08}{wed-City},
                    divorce={2012-05-08}{cityDIV},
                    %            death={}{},
                    comment={\textbf{maidSurname \ref{sec:maidSurname}}},
                }
                c[id=FTJ90]{
                    male,
                    name={\pref{F} T  \surn{mySurname}},
                    birth={1990-05-23}{City}
                }
                c[id=BMJ93]{
                    male,
                    name={\pref{B} M \surn{mySurname}},
                    birth={1993-11-05}{City}
                }
                c[id=CGJ93]{
                    male,
                    name={\pref{C} G \surn{mySurname}},
                    birth={1993-11-05}{City},
                }
                %parent[id=D32]
            }
        }
        
    \end{genealogypicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you very much Simon.